# Apache Ignite : Not able to query Select...in() clause with spring boot

Tags: ignite

I am not able to use IN() clause with apache ignite using spring-boot.

I have tried two ways but both are not working.

Please help me to solve the issue.
repository:

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "test")
public interface TestRepo extends IgniteRepository<Test, TestKey>{


    @Query("SELECT distinct subscribers FROM test where city  in :cities")
    List<Integer> selectAll(@Param("cities") List<String> cities, Pageable pageable);

    List<Test> findByCityIn( List<String> cities);
```

error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ""test"".""TEST""._KEY, ""test"".""TEST""._VAL FROM TEST WHERE ((TEST.CITY IN ?[*])) "; expected "("; SQL statement:
SELECT "test"."TEST"._KEY, "test"."TEST"._VAL FROM Test WHERE ((Test.city IN ?)) [42001-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
```

Comment: Could you please share a complete runnable reproducer? And also please specify the Ignite, H2 and Spring Data versions you're using.

Comment: ignite version: 2.3

spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE

spring-boot-starter-jdbc 1.5.9

Comment: Thanks for the versions, but a runnable example to illustrate the problem would still be needed.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT "test"."TEST"._KEY, "test"."TEST"._VAL FROM Test WHERE ((Test.city IN ?))`

First of all, question mark should definitely be in parens: `IN (?)`.

Second, you are trying to bind multiple values (in list) to the same question mark at once. I'm not sure that will work. Docs tell that it won't work for `IN` but would for the case described below.

Third, using `IN` with Ignite is not recommended for performance reasons, and using `join table()` is suggested instead:
https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#section-sql-performance-and-usability-considerations